# Removing Unwanted blob in image

Tags: image, matlab

How can i remove unwanted blob from this image so that only text area is visible in the image?[Image with unwanted blob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okYSB.jpg)

Comment: You can remove most of them using `bwareaopen`. 
https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html

Comment: Do you need to do this for multiple images where each has a differently sized textbox or just for this single one?

Comment: Yes for multiple images

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is always text, I suggested first applying an OCR to recognize the text.

```
I=imread('image'jpg');
ocrResults   = ocr(image);
Iocr         = insertObjectAnnotation(image, 'rectangle', ...
                       ocrResults.WordBoundingBoxes, ...
                       ocrResults.WordConfidences);
figure; imshow(Iocr);
```

And the result should be something like this:
[image: Iocr]

After you apply OCR, in the variable ocrResults you will have a field that will be CharacterBoundingBoxes, where through this you can create a binary mask of ones (on the position of the boxes) and erase everything else (zeros). Of course some noise will be detected as text, but if you work a bit with morphological operations as explained above (bwareaopen) you will have better results.

Comment: If this solution solved your problem, please accept the answer